# Unfortunately, Camera has stopped when using FileProvider

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent, android-fileprovider

I'm using the device's camera using an intent. When I'm using Uri.fromFile(File file) the app doesn't stop and the image is saved to the destination folder. But when I changed the Uri.fromFile into FileProvider.getUriForFile() the camera stops working after taking a photo. How do I fix this issue and How can I successfully save the captured image into a destination folder?

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button button;
    ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initInstances();
    }

    public void initInstances(){
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.photoButton);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageId);
    }

    public void takePhoto(View view) {
        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());

        File storageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Bry-Test");
        Uri.from

        storageDir.mkdirs();


        File image = new File(storageDir, "QR_" + timeStamp + ".png");
//        Uri photoUri = Uri.fromFile(image);
        Uri photoUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this, "com.test.bry", image);
        cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoUri);
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 1);

    }
}
```

AndroidManifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.test.bry">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <provider
            android:authorities="com.test.bry"
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">

                <meta-data
                    android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                    android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />

        </provider>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

provider_paths

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>

</paths>
```

Comment: Please don't repeat questions. Simply editing your original post with any new information you have will bump it to the top of the active queue.

Comment: Please do a test where you open an output stream for that uri yourself snd try to write to it.

Comment: Please tell the value of `photoUri.toString()`.

Comment: `name="external_files"`. In which way are you using `name`? What does it?